# Maximum call stack size exceeded error even though I am not using recursion

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, stack-overflow

In my node application, I have a route that is causing a maximum call stack size error. This happens when I try to push a user from mongodb into an array. Here is the route that is causing the error:

```
router.get('/join', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user.id).populate('room');
    const rooms = await Room.find({ full: false }).populate('players.user');
    let room;
    if (rooms.length <= 0 || !rooms) {
      room = new Room();
    } else {
      rooms.sort((a, b) => (a.playerCount > b.playerCount ? -1 : 1));
      room = rooms[0];
    }
    user.room = room;
    await user.save();
    if (room.players.length == room.playerCount) {
      room.players.push({ user });
      // room.playerCount += 1;
    }
    await room.save();
    res.json(room);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});
```

The error only occurs when I keep the line: `room.players.push({ user });`. Here is the code for the room and user schemas:

```
const RoomSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  players: [
    {
      user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
      },
      hand: {
        type: Array,
        default: []
      }
    }
  ],
  playerCount: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
  full: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  }
}
```

User:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  earning: {
    type: Number,
    default: 50000
  },
  wins: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    }
  ],
  losses: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    }
  ],
  room: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Room'
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It seems you DO have a self-referential definition - a `User` has a `Room` which refers to that `User`... etc. See if this GitHub issue helps you: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6580#issuecomment-431910074

Comment: I would try to change this line `room.players.push({ user });` to `room.players.push(user._id);` or `room.players.push(user);` I think there should be no  `{}` around the user. But `user._id` is suficient.

Comment: @Molda Your solution worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you have imported the same js file twice, by mistake. It would be possibly one of the reasons this could happen.

Comment: But then why would the error only occur when the push is called?

Comment: Can you comment that line and check. Is the same exception is throwing.

Comment: No. Once I comment that line, the exception goes away.